# How to reverse this expression using notepad++ regex

Tags: regex, expression, notepad++

I have a file which is full of these lines(and some other stuff) and "SUMMARY" is an identical start of line.

```
SUMMARY:1991/04/08
SUMMARY:1211/08/10
```

the numbers can be anything. I want to reverse it so it will be like:

```
SUMMARY:08/04/1991
SUMMARY:10/08/1211
```

How can I do it with notepad++ or any other software.
by the way, can you give me a refrence for this regex replacing thing.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) here.

Search for

```
^SUMMARY:(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})
```

and replace with

```
SUMMARY:\3/\2/\1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also capture them in 4 groups as below.

Find what: `(\d{4})(/\d+/)(\d+)`
Replace with: `$3$2$1`